# How to move the default folder for headless virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm (trying) to use Virtualbox on the remote computer - headless mode.

When creating a virtual machine, with

```
VBoxManage createvm --ostype Windows7 --name MYBOX --register
```

it created it in my `$HOME/VirtualBox VMs/` direictory. It is really annoying to have a space in the path. ;(

How to change the default path from "VirtualBox VMs" to something other with commandline?

Answer (score 14):

just discovered - tt is simple:

```
VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder /new/path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use `mklink /J junction` for folders on another drive, that might solve your problem
but first you should move "VirtualBox VMs" to another drive and then create a link to that directory.

**Example:**

```
mklink /J "%HOMEPATH%/VirtualBox VMs/" "%SOME_DRIVE%\%YOUR_MOVED_VMs_FOLDER%"
```